# Chrome Extension - convert to bitly and copy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i've put together this code that in my (null) experience should be close to do what i need ( add utm to current link, convert it to bitly and then copy to clipboard)

ive tried to debug as much as i can, but as i say im not an expert on Javascript and cuold not get very far, also havent been able to troubleshoot from Devtools on chrome since it is an extension, but basically im getting the correct address but (html has a popup with the correct address) its not copying anything to the clipboard. what did i do wrong? (this code is a mix of other sources, as i said i dont know javascript, i mostly use python and im no expert there either. 
Script.js:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function ShortLinkBitly( pLongUrl ) { /*pLongUrl is the long URL*/
    if ( !pLongUrl.match(/(ftp|http|https):\/\//i) ) {
        return "Error: Link must start with a protocol (e.g.: http or https).";
    }
    var apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    var username = 'XXXXXXX';
    /*Ajax call*/
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=' + username + '&apiKey=' + apiKey + '&format=json&longUrl=' + encodeURIComponent(pLongUrl),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function( response ) {
            if ( response.status_code == 500) {
                /*500 status code means the link is malformed.*/
                return "Error: Invalid link.";
            } else if ( response.status_code != 200) {

                /*If response is not 200 then an error ocurred. It can be a network issue or bitly is down.*/
                return "Error: Service unavailable.";

                /*Uncomment the following line only for debugging purposes*/
                /*console.log('Response: ' + response.status_code + '-' + response.status_txt);*/
            }
            else
                return response.data.url; /* OK, return the short link */
        },

        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    var urlArea = document.getElementById("urlArea");       
    urlArea.innerHTML = tabs[0].url.concat("?utm_medium=callcenter&utm_source=callcenter&utm_campaign=TestMauro");
    var URL = urlArea.innerHTML
    URL = ShortLinkBitly(URL)
        var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute('value', URL);
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Link copied successfully";
    });
}
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3 id="title">Copylink</h3>
<textarea id="urlArea"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I also checked my bitly account and no address has been created so clearly something is not working there? 
Thanks all!

Comment: Im preeeety sure the error is in the last 7-8 lines of scripts.js, but dun know what to look for really

Comment: Update: i figured the bitly  part of the js code must be wrong so i separated that code and made it rune alone with a standard address, and it works, it gets to bitly but the function returns "undefined" ¿?  from bitly i can see that the link was created, yet function returns "undefined"  why?

Comment: This is a classic [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321) - your "return response.data.url" doesn't do what you intend it to. As shown and explained in the linked topic you need to put the code that wants to use the result inside the callback or use Promise.

Comment: Some other notes: 1) Assuming this is inside a browser_action popup, the first step is to look at the right devtools console: right-click **the popup** and click "inspect". 2) Include jquery.js within your extension directory and load it locally because loading remote code into the privileged context of extensions is a very bad idea 3) Make sure you've declared site permissions properly in your manifest.json.

Comment: Well, u are probably right for what i see, i understand the problem perfectly, but i don't understand enough JS to apply what should be the solution (callbacks seem waaaay too complicated for me since i only started checking JS yesterday, lol)... damn i hate myself.

Comment: The "code that wants to use the result" is what you have after ShortLinkBitly(URL) call. You can simply move it up instead of "return response.data.url;" and of course use `response.data.url` in place of `URL`.

Comment: well, i changed  the code to include $.ajaxSetup({async: false}); and still im getting undefined..... :S any thought? im most likely doing something terribly wrong

Comment: Well... after 3 more hours of testing i still cant do it. it just doesnt work anyway i try. i give up on Javascript.